# where condition in MySQL Insert statement

Tags: c#, mysql

Can I use where condition in Insert statement???? 
I have coded like this, its showng me an error call MySQLException was unhandled, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE RegistrationID='3'' at line 1. My code:-

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO registration(DueAmount) VALUES ('"+textBox5.Text + "') WHERE RegistrationID='"+textBox2.Text+"'",connection);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing 2 different statements.

- An `UPDATE` statement updates an existing row in your table.
- An `INSERT` statement adds a new row in your table.

I think you want to use an `UPDATE` statement and modify an existing row.

```
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("
UPDATE Registration Set DueAmount= '"+textBox5.Text 
+ "' WHERE RegistrationID='"+textBox2.Text+"'",connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of `INSERT` doesn't have `WHERE` clause. I think you want `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`,

```
UPDATE registration 
SET DueAmount = 'txt5'
WHERE RegistrationID = 'txt2'
```

the only way you can use `WHERE` in `SELECT` is when you are using `INSERT INTO....SELECT` statement.

one more thing, since you are using `ADO.NET`, make sure that you parameterized your query to avoid `SQL Injection`, and use `USING` statement.

```
string query = "UPDATE  registration 
                SET     DueAmount = @dateAmount
                WHERE   RegistrationID = @RegID"
using (MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query,connection))
{
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateAmount", textBox5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegID", textBox2.Text);

    // other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` with `WHERE` doesn't make sense.  `INSERT` always inserts a new row.  You might be looking for `REPLACE INTO` which does a insert if that record doesnt exist or an update if it does based on its primary key.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` puts a new line to database. You can not put a new line `WHERE` sth is sth. But you can `UPDATE` it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an UPDATE statement.

tHS SYNTAX IS SIMILAR: "UPDATE registration SET DueAmount = '" + textBox5.Text + "' WHERE RegistrationID='"+textBox2.Text+"'"

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Update`

```
var query = "UPDATE Registration SET DueAmount= $Paremeter1 WHERE RegistrationID = $Paremeter2";
var cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

cmd1 .Parameters.AddWithValue("$Paremeter1", textBox5.Text);
cmd1 .Parameters.AddWithValue("$Paremeter2", textBox2.Text);
```